# Custom marshalling to bson and JSON (Golang & mgo)

Tags: json, mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I have the following type in Golang:

`type Base64Data []byte`

In order to support unmarshalling a base64 encoded string to this type, I did the following:

```
func (b *Base64Data) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if len(data) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    content, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(data[1 : len(data)-1]))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *b = []byte(xml)
    return nil
}
```

Now I also want to be able to marshal and unmarshal it to mongo database, using mgo Golang library.
The problem is that I already have documents there stored as base64 encoded string, so I have to maintain that.
I tried to do the following:

```
func (b Base64Data) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(b)), nil
}

func (b *Base64DecodedXml) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    var s string
    var err error
    if err = raw.Unmarshal(&s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *b, err = base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
    return err
}
```

So that after unmarshaling, the data is already decoded, so I need to encode it back, and return it as a string so it will be written to db as a string (and vice versa)
For that I implemented bson getter and setter, but it seems only the getter is working properly

JSON unmarshaling from base64 encoded string works, as well marshaling it to database. but unmarshling setter seems to not be called at all.

Can anyone suggest what I'm missing, so that I'll be able to properly hold the data decoded in memory, but encoded string type?

This is a test I tried to run:

```
b := struct {
    Value shared.Base64Data `json:"value" bson:"value"`
}{}
s := `{"value": "PHJvb3Q+aGVsbG88L3Jvb3Q+"}`
require.NoError(t, json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &b))
t.Logf("%v", string(b.Value))
b4, err := bson.Marshal(b)
require.NoError(t, err)
t.Logf("%v", string(b4))
require.NoError(t, bson.Unmarshal(b4, &b))
t.Logf("%v", string(b.Value))
```

Comment: Your code works. Please show us how you use it.

Comment: @icza Added an example

Comment: And what is `b3` in your code?

Comment: @icza Sorry it was just `b3 := Base64Data(b.Value)` but I removed it without fully editing the post. Edited correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't marshal any value with [`bson.Marshal()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Marshal), only maps and struct values.

If you want to test it, pass a `map`, e.g. [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#M) to `bson.Marshal()`:

```
var x = Base64Data{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}

dd, err := bson.Marshal(bson.M{"data": x})
fmt.Println(string(dd), err)
```

Your code works as-is, and as you intend it to. Try to insert a wrapper value to verify it:

```
c := sess.DB("testdb").C("testcoll")

var x = Base64Data{0x01, 0x02, 0x03}
if err := c.Insert(bson.M{
    "data": x,
}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will save the data as a `string`, being the Base64 encoded form.

Of course if you want to load it back into a value of type `Base64Data`, you will also need to define the `SetBSON(raw Raw) error` method too ([`bson.Setter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) interface).

Comment: thanks. I was testing it wrongly. Indeed marsaling to bson works well. So I actually need to complete my implementation by writing the setter. but It doesnt seems to be called at all. I edited my question, can you please suggest what Im doing wrong with the setter?

Comment: @buddy123 You save it as a value of type `string`, so you should unmarshal the raw value into a value of type `string`, not `[]byte`.

Comment: this got me confused. You're right, yet it still doesnt work when I unmarshal to a string. I edited my setter

Comment: @buddy123 Because you used a wrong receiver type: `b *Base64DecodedXml`, it should be `b *Base64Data`.